# Marriage in Judgement-day

Tags: nikah, sharia, husband-wife, day-of-judgement, love

Allah Almighty has said people will get what they wish for in Jannah or Heaven. What if you wish for a woman who is someone else's wife? And The woman also want to be with you, What will be the decision of Allah? Plz answer me with Proves.

Comment: One important thing to note is that the emotions/feelings of those who will live in Paradise will not be like that of us today. They will be granted freedom from greed, jealousy & anger. They will NOT imagine things which would be considered immoral.

Comment: I don't have any feeling of greed ,jealousy or anger ,I love her and she loves me, just cause of some circumstance we couldn't married each other :(

Comment: @QaisarMohammadi If you accept the state you're in right now and have patience then insha Allah, Allah will reward you in a way better than you anticipated. Also, the Hoor in Jannah will be like no other in terms of beauty, personality, and whatever you wish for. The Hoor will be of better satisfaction!

Answer (score 1):

The residents of paradise will be very well satisfied by there Lord. At the moment you both are on earth and accept the fact that you are not married to each other. She should love her husband and you should love your wife this is best for you both.

In paradise your spouses will be given to you way more beautified. And beauty of paradise will be so much more then that of this world that there is no comparison.

Imagine a person today prays to have some latest gadget or car of today in paradise, if he gets that in paradise he will look stupid in eye of a person that will come to earth few years later as he will be praising an old school item.